# AngularCli not loads image

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Just a simple question:

I have an Angular2 application, I serve it using **ng serve** and the application are properly rendered.

The problem is this:

The css are loaded properly but the image no.

For example, if I put a css file and an image file in the **same folder** and I try to access them by direct link like these:

## css

http://localhost:4200/assets/distAdminLte2/css/AdminLTE.min.css

## image

http://localhost:4200/assets/distAdminLte2/css/mosconi.jpg

The css is rendered but the image is not rendered...

How to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: You need to show your code.

Comment: for wich file Augustine ?

Comment: how you are setting the  image path in html ?

Comment: Are you trying to access the image via your components html, or the components css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your image path in .angular-cli.json.

```
"assets":[
   "img/img.png"]
```

Comment: Shouldn't be the case, the cli takes the entire assets folder, you shouldn't need to pick individual files.